# GAE Update Question

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a strange question.
What I want to do is update my GAE version from 1.3.5 to 1.4.1/1.4.0.
After installing, I want to run dev_appserver.
But there is a error:

```
ERROR    2011-01-19 21:50:11,262 dev_appserver.py:3214] Exception encountered handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3184, in _HandleRequest
    response = RewriteResponse(outfile, self.rewriter_chain)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2882, in RewriteResponse
    response_rewriter(response)
TypeError: DownloadRewriter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Note: I didn't change my code and it worked very well on GAE 1.3.5
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I faced many strange problems with GAE. Uninstall and reinstall and you should be fine, at least I hope. Otherwise, you may like to edit your answer and paste the whole stack trace so that we can help you more.

Comment: @systempuntoout:No, I haven't rebooted. I'll try later.. Thanks.

Comment: @Promather: I'll reboot firstly.if the problem still exist, I'll paste the whole stack , thanks very much.

Comment: @systempuntoout: I have rebooted alreaday. But it still can't work...T_T

Comment: @Promather: How do I get my whole stack in python???

Comment: It would really help if you included more information - the code that you're trying to run, and what you're trying to do when this occurs.

Comment: @Nick: I was trying to update my GAE version. I was using 1.3.5 version.But I want to use new service of bulkloader( http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). I have to upgrade my GAE version. That's the background. 

And when I finish my install, I want to run dev_appserver to open my website( http://localhost:8080/). And the error occurs.

The most interesting thing is I didn't change my code at all. It worked very well on GAE 1.3.5. But it can't work on 1.4.1/1.4.0. That's why I said it's a strange problem.

Comment: I have tried to close my eclipse, reboot, uninstall 1.4.1 and reinstall 1.3.5(work well again), uninstall 1.3.5 and reinstall 1.4.1 again (still can't work)  Thanks.^^

Comment: @Shine What matters, though, is what your code is, and what you're trying to execute when this occurs. Obviously, this issue is not one everyone gets - and so there's something specific to your code that's causing it. We can't tell what that is without _seeing_ your code.

Comment: @Nick, But I don't know which part code should I paste. Cause I didn't change my project at all. Or can you tell me what part is important? T_T

Comment: @Shine, sorry for being late. By the whole stack, I meant anything you get after executing dev_server, so it seems that you already did so. I would recommend sending this question to Google AppEngine guys, because they are the ones who understand every file in AppEngine and will most probably be able to help you.

Comment: @Shine The code behind whatever handler it is that you're invoking when you send whatever request it is that triggers this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved. 
We reinstalled gae again at "different folder"
"Different folder" is a key.
If you uninstall gae at the default (same) folder (c:\program files\google\google_appengine), the problems still exist.

So we installed it at c:\program files\goole\google_appending_x (x means any word).
Then it can work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

We found when I reinstall GAE 3.5 above. My C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py

Line 2887: def RewriteResponse code is not correct.
The right version is:

```
def RewriteResponse(response_file,
                response_rewriters=None,
                request_headers=None):
  if response_rewriters is None:
    response_rewriters = CreateResponseRewritersChain()

  response = AppServerResponse(response_file)
  for response_rewriter in response_rewriters:
    if response_rewriter.func_code.co_argcount == 1:
      response_rewriter(response)
    else:
      response_rewriter(response, request_headers)

  return response
```

But my version is

```
def RewriteResponse(response_file,
                    response_rewriters=None,
                    request_headers=None):
  if response_rewriters is None:
    response_rewriters = CreateResponseRewritersChain()

  response = AppServerResponse(response_file)
  for response_rewriter in response_rewriters:
    response_rewriter(response)

  return response
```

There is no if-else . 
So the solution is that install GAE at c:\Program files\Google\google_appengine_x....
not at default folder. 
Then it will be correct. ^^